# Импорт psd в dreamweaver

Tags: вёрстка, dreamweaver

Как импортировать фотошоповские слои в дримвивер? Вроде как можно, сохраняю для веб сайт в фотошопе, а оно одной картинкой сохраняется. ((

Comment: Вообщееее народ обленился %) Когда сделают прогу, которая будет транслировать мысли в html5+css3? `@_@`

@thedarkelf, "Сохранить для веб" означает, что картинка будет оптимизированной для веба (меньше размер, чересстрочно и т.п.), а не "для дримвивера")

Comment: Ни фига, можно как он хочет. Тут ты резко неправ: в Фотошопе уже давно куча кнопок сделать .-.-.-.-то есть.

Answer (score 1):

Слои нельзя. Можно области. Для этого надо использовать инструмент **slice**, а потом выбрать опцию html, все рисунки в меню "save for web".
Получится файл, в котором каждая область будет отдельным дивом.
Пример работы этой связки, например тут: 
[manga-sushi](http://manga-sushi.net)
Только тут не дивы, а TDшки. Так поступали ранние версии фотошопа(точнее, утилита ImageReady, которая впоследствии была в ФШ встроена)